# R - odbc - how do I close a DB connection?

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc

I'm able to establish the connection fine however I have been unable to figure out how to close the connection once I'm done.  Any suggestion?

```
if (!require('odbc')) install.packages('odbc')

con <- dbConnect(odbc(), 
                 Driver = "SQL Server", 
                 Server = "localhost", 
                 Database = "VCF", 
                 UID = "**********",
                 PWD = "**********"                 
                 )

dbWriteTable(con, "raw_myserversDF", myserversDF, append = TRUE)
```

Comment: `DBI::dbDisconnect(con)`. In `?dbConnect`, it says: *"See Also: 'dbDisconnect()' to disconnect from a database"*.

Comment: Some good references to learn how to use database connections in R: https://db.rstudio.com/dbi/ and https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/deployment/

Comment: The `odbc` package is really meant to *augment* the `DBI` package, where all of its functions (methods) extend the `DBI` generic methods. For this, a lot of the documentation suggests `library(DBI)` (not `library(odbc)`), and `dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),...)` (which is now using `DBI::dbConnect` instead). With that, if you read `?dbConnect`, you should be reading DBI's version (use `?DBI::dbConnect` if you are seeing both), and that is where my first comment is from.

Answer (score 0):

From r2evans "DBI::dbDisconnect(con). In ?dbConnect, it says: "See Also: 'dbDisconnect()' to disconnect from a database"."

Answer (score -1):

I think this would help you by using RODBC. I also faced the same issue previously

```
con <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(...)
on.exit(RODBC::odbcClose(con))
```

Comment: `odbc` is the function exported by the `odbc` package, not `RODBC`.